# Is the column-family based data model of Cassandra the same as the column-family based data modle of Google's BigTable?

Tags: database, cassandra, bigtable

Well if I understand correctly, Google's proprietary BigTable is built on Google's proprietary GFS.

So at the homepage of http://cassandra.apache.org/ they are actually claiming to have BigTable's column-family based data model?

I mean i really do not see how it is possible.

Is the column-family based data model of Cassandra the same as the column-family based data model of Google's BigTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has published research papers about some of its core technologies, for instance [Big Table](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) and [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html). Cassandra is saying they use the concept from the Big Table paper and not Google's implementation.

Comment: wow that's generous of them to give up share their technologies with their competitors

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra's data model is related to Bigtable's but not identical.  "Inspired by" would be more accurate.

For instance, Cassandra supports indexing column values which Bigtable does not.

See http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/data_model/index for more on Cassandra's data model.